# Referencing PivotItems

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to reference the item selected in a `PivotField`. If I use the following code, then I get a message box with the word 'Month':

```
MsgBox PT.PivotFields("Month").Value
```

What I would like is the message box to show the month that is currently selected - so if February is the month selected in the `PivotField` then 'February' will show rather than 'Month'. I would think to do this using `PivotItems`, although I seem to be only able to define this using the below code:

```
MsgBox PT.PivotFields("Month").PivotItems("February").Value
```

This would return me the static result of 'February' but will not work once a different month is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected PivotItem, use the PivotItem property of the Range class.

```
MsgBox Activecell.PivotItem.Value
```

If the activecell isn't within a PivotTable, you'll get an error. You might prefer

```
Dim pi As PivotItem

On Error Resume Next
    Set pi = ActiveCell.PivotItem
On Error GoTo 0

If Not pi Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox pi.Value
End If
```

to avoid the error.